# SUM of differences between rows in table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table with call records. Each call has a 'state' CALLSTART and CALLEND, and each call has a unique 'callid'. Also for each record there is a unique autoincrement 'id'. Each row has a MySQL TIMESTAMP field.

I would like to know the total duration of phone calls of the current day. This means substracting every the timestamp of each row with a CALLEND state from the row with the same callid and CALLSTART state, and taking the sum of all those.

How do I do this in MySQL? Or do I need a while loop in php?

Screenshot of table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEnUJ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(differences)) FROM
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)))as differences 
FROM table
GROUP BY callid)x
```

Assuming MAX(timestamp) is the end of the call 
and MIN(timestamp) is the beginning of the call for each group.

Comment: Hi, I get several SQL errors trying to run this. It seems on the right track but I can't figure it out. I also made a screenshot of the table to make the problem more clear: http://imgur.com/gmdeSaY

Comment: I had to switch the MIN and MAX because otherwise I would get a negative value. Other than that it works now! Thanks

Comment: @StevenH Yes,TIMESTAMPPDIFF subtracts the first argument from the second,my bad.

Comment: As a follow up, all the calls in the example also had an EXAMPLE state. This is not always the case. Is there a way to only calculate the sum for those calls that have a row with CONNECTED state? This way calls that were not answered won't be counted.

Comment: @StevenH add after tableName WHERE state IN('CONNECTED').Put state also in the SELECT if this doesnt work.

Comment: The 'differences' go to 0 if I add this unfortunately

Comment: @StevenH `HAVING state IN('CONNECTED')` at the end.

Comment: Zero rows return if I do this:
SELECT state, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(differences)) FROM
(SELECT state, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)))as differences 
FROM records
GROUP BY callid)x
HAVING state IN('CONNECTED')

Comment: Sorry for keep asking, I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @StevenH   at the end of the subquery,after group by.

Comment: Now it returns one row with two times NULL :P
I did: SELECT state, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(differences)) FROM
(SELECT state, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)))as differences 
FROM records
GROUP BY callid HAVING state IN('CONNECTED'))x

Comment: If I do SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(differences)) FROM
(SELECT state, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)))as differences 
FROM records
GROUP BY callid HAVING state IN('CONNECTED'))x
Removing one unneeded collumn I still get NULL

Comment: @StevenH I`m retarded tonight,sorry.Ask a new question, I cant see what I`m doing wrong .

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway :) You already helped me get miles further than I was.